# Hidden fields from model appear when model is a relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

### Situation

So this just happend to me. I have 3 models that have a relation with eachother. My schema is like this:

-- RollingStocks

- id
- name
- [...]

-- Users

- id
- name
- [..]

-- Tasks

- id
- description
- projectleader_id // Corresponds with App\User or App\Group
- projectleader_type // Corresponds with App\User or App\Group
- rolling_stock_id
- [...]

My models have a relationship with eachother:

RollingStock.php

```
public function task()
{
return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function task()
{
return $this->morphMany(Task::class, 'projectleader');
}
```

Task.php

```
public function RollingStock()
{
return $this->belongsTo(RollingStock::class);
}

public function projectleader()
{
return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In my User model I have set the 'password' and 'remember_token' as `$hidden` which looks like this:

User.php

```
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

---

### Problem

With this little introduction, I will now bring you to my problem. When I fetch in my RollingStocksController all tasks WITH the projectleaders with the following query, the results include the 'hidden' fields in the User model (as projectleader) as well.

```
$rollingStock = RollingStock::with('task.projectleader')->find($id); // ID matches the ID of the RollingStock I'm trying to fetch)
```

### Result

If I die and dump (`dd()`) the object has it's relations, BUT then the fields 'password' and 'remember_token' from the `User model` are vissible and printable to the screen if I loop through the object.

Is there a way to hide the fields, even if the model is (eager) loaded as a relation?

Comment: You can use except method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-except

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$hidden` only hides fields when the result is returned as JSON.  It is easy to forget, but the section of the docs is titled ["Hiding Attributes From JSON"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json).

In your controller, try:

```
return $rollingStock;
```

Laravel will convert that to JSON, and your hidden fields will not show up.  Change it to:

```
dd($rollingStock);
```

and they *will* appear, as the result is not JSON, just a dumped variable.

Comment: OK... That's why! Now I understand. So I've to find a solution to use @Ahsan method on dot-nested relations in my Eloquent query.

Comment: Bummer... ````except()```` only works on a collection and not on an object.

Comment: Oh :-(  You can of course `unset()` etc but that is not very convenient. OTOH unless you actually choose to display the fields in your view they won't show up, right?

Comment: Very true, so it's not that much of a problem, but I was like: "what's not fetched, can't be mistakenly accessed", for the sake of security. And because of the ````$hidden```` property on the model I assumed (...) it wouldn't be showed anyway... ;-)